# Rename the [google-static-maps] tag to [google-maps-static-api]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

*Google Static Maps API* was renamed quite some time ago (no idea exactly when) to [*Google Maps Static API*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static).

Therefore, I would suggest to **rename** the [google-static-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-static-maps) tag to [google-maps-static-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-static-api).

This would also reflect the naming of other related Google API tags such as [google-street-view-static-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-street-view-static-api), [google-directions-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-directions-api), [google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api), [google-routes-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-routes-api), [google-roads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-roads-api), [google-geocoding-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-geocoding-api), etc.